# Updating Session after revoking individual permissions

Tags: android, session, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to give users an option to set/revoke publishing permission via checkbox (Facebook SDK for Android). Code is provided below. Everything works fine except that after revoking the code responsible for checking publishing permissions fails miserably.

I understand that Session has no way of knowing if user has revoked any permissions after loggin in. What is the correct way to handle this kind of situation? Do I have to query available permissions manually, or is there a way to seamlessly recreate session with basic permissions?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    publishCheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.publishCheckbox);
        publishCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) v;
                if (chb.isChecked() && checkForPublishPermission() == false){
                    requestPublishPermissions();                            
                }
                else{
                    removePublishPermissions();
                }   

            }

        });
    ...
}

private void requestPublishPermissions() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if ( session!= null && session.isOpened()){
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS).setRequestCode(REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(callback);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }               
}   

private void removePublishPermissions() {       
    Request r = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION_PATH, null, HttpMethod.DELETE);
    r.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            publishCheckbox.setEnabled(true);                               
        }
    });
    r.executeAsync();
    publishCheckbox.setEnabled(false);
}

private boolean checkForPublishPermission(){
    boolean result = false;

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpened()) {
        result = false;
    }
    else{
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (permissions.containsAll(PERMISSIONS)) {
            result = true;
        }
    }       

    return(result);
}   

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) { 
        ...
        publishCheckbox.setChecked(checkForPublishPermission());
        ...
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {          
        ...                             
    }       
}
```

Comment: I'm also waiting an answer. If the user delete the whole application from his online account Session recognize it and will you logout. But if the user just remove a permission the Session wont update his permission.

Answer (score 1):

Well I ended up requesting user permissions each time I needed such a check, something along these lines:

```
private void checkForPublishPermission(){
    mPublishCheckbox.setEnabled(false);
    Request r = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), PUBLISH_ACTIONS_PERMISSION_PATH, null, HttpMethod.GET);
    r.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if (response != null) {
                GraphObject o = response.getGraphObject();              
                    if ( o != null){
                        JSONArray data = o.getInnerJSONObject().optJSONArray("data");                       
                        mCanPublish = (data.optJSONObject(0).has("publish_actions"))?true:false;                            
                        mPublishCheckbox.setChecked(mCanPublish);                                                       
                    }
            }
            mPublishCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    r.executeAsync();
}
```