# Is there an efficient way to check if permissions have been revoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, user-permissions

So I am building an asp.net application, that features a table with permissions, that grant users access to certain features. There are many permissions. I am saving these permissions on log in, in the session object. Is there an efficient way to check if changes have been made to that user, without re-querying the database for permissions that haven't changed? I don't really care about, if permissions are added because they can just log in again. I only care if they are revoked?

I found a similar question here below but no answers:

[Updating Session after revoking individual permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249980/updating-session-after-revoking-individual-permissions)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't.  If you want changes to take effect immediately (without requiring the user to log out and log in again), you have to requery the database.

Comment: Presumably, you could revoke the session when permissions are changed; this forces a logout.  It would be pretty rude, though.

Comment: I wouldn't think that it would be possible to do this and guarantee consistency. Anything else would be a bad-practice hawkish sort of solution. You could store temp data in a cookie that you also check.. but again.. I would just use the data-base.

Comment: The reason you didn't see an answer at that other question was that the OP mashed it into the top of his *question.*  He concluded that he needed to "use the source, Luke."